# how to iterate through list inside another list - json + js

Tags: javascript, json, django, ajax

I'm trying to iterate over a list inside another list , here is my data :

> (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
> 0: {id: 9, check_in: '2021-10-02T15:58:00', check_out: '2021-10-05T10:17', visitors: Array(4)}
> 1: {id: 10, check_in: '2021-10-06T21:12:00', check_out: '2021-10-09T15:00', visitors: Array(4)}
> 2: {id: 11, check_in: '2021-10-27T21:34:00', check_out: '2021-10-29T21:34', visitors: Array(4)}
> length: 3

my visitors array looks like this :

> visitors: Array(4)
> 0: {full_name: 'name1'}
> 1: {full_name: 'name2'}
> length: 2

and so on ,

and here is my js code with html

```js
        $.ajax({        
        url:'my_url',
        type:'json',
        method:'GET',
        success:function(data){
            let booking = data.lists
            let visitors = data.lists.visitors
            console.log(visitors)                        
            let content='';           
                for(j=0; j< booking.visitors;j++){
                    
                    console.log(j)

                }                 
                    for(i=0;i<booking.length;i++){
                        content+='<div class="border border-purple-900 rounded-xl p-1 text-sm  text-center">';
                            content+='<p>'+booking[i]['visitors']['full_name']['full_name']+'</p>';
                        content+='</div>';

                        content+='<div class="mt-1">';
                        let check_in= new Date(booking[i]["check_in"]).toLocaleDateString([], {
                            day: '2-digit',month: '2-digit',year: 'numeric' ,hour: '2-digit', minute:'2-digit'});  
                        if(booking[i]['check_out']){
                            check_out = new Date(booking[i]['check_out']).toLocaleDateString([], {
                                day: '2-digit',month: '2-digit',year: 'numeric' ,hour: '2-digit', minute:'2-digit'});
        
                        }else{
                            check_out = 'not mentioned'
                        }                        
                        content+='<p>'+check_in+' to ' +check_out+ '</p>'
                        content+='</div>'

                    }
                
            content+='</div>'

        $("#current-booking").html(content);

    }});
```

and `console.log(visitors)`  return undefined ! , now i dont know how to return back list of full names from ajax ? is there something i have to change please ?

and here is my views.py

```
current_booking = Booking.objects.filter(leave=False,room_no__room_no=room_no)  
visitors_booking = BookingVisitor.objects.filter(booking__room_no__room_no=room_no,booking__leave=False)

lists = []
visitors = []
for j in visitors_booking:
    visitors.append({
    'full_name':j.visitor.full_name
    })

for i in current_booking:
    obj = {
        'id':i.pk,
        'check_in':i.check_in,
        'check_out':check_out,
        'visitors':visitors
    }
    lists.append(obj)

return JsonResponse({'success':True,'lists':lists})
```

thanks in advance ..

Comment: i think to make it easy you can just render a partial html,after you can add a div with id,and after success inside the ajax you can just append the data to the id i think it is more easier.

Comment: by example with that you can just do this  $("#current-booking").append(data); inside your success function.